# observer-only jgroups cluster members?

Tags: java, jgroups

We are using [jGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) to build two clusters: "server" and "app". They are independent clusters, running on different machines (communicating with each-other over JMS). Some of our code needs to run on only one node in a cluster, so we use the "coordinator" / master concept in jGroups to choose the node where to run that code.

We have yet another requirement: we need to notify server admin, when any of our cluster nodes die. We could have each cluster node monitor for membership changes, but **we cannot send failure notifications from "app" cluster nodes**, only from "server" cluster nodes.

**Finally, the question**: is it possible to join a jGroups channel/cluster without participating in the coordinator/master election? So that "server" cluster nodes could join "app" cluster as observer-only members (receiving "view changed" events, but not participating in the elections)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on the requirement, but the following solution might work:

Include a "nodeType" property in your application and read it from a properties file. 
Change the election algorithm so that only "app" node types participate in election, node types "server" discard the election messages.

Comment: How familiar are you with jGroups? Maybe you can give couple of more pointers in the right direction? For example, how can I change the election algorithm (what interface to implement, how to configure jgroups to pick up my version of this algorithm, etc)?